# Is possible on android to create tab bar to slide up(shows/be visible) and slide down(disappear/invisible)?

Tags: android

Is possible on android to create tab bar to slide up(shows/be visible) and slide down(disappear/invisible) ? I need to create to tab bar be visible 10% of height (invisible state) then slide up with finger and be visible 100% (visible state).
 Is there any example which solves this problem ?